# MySQLAdapter does not change the values

Tags: c#, mysql

```
 public static int update(DataTable dt, string id, string table){
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE " + table + " SET username=?username,password=?password WHERE id=" + id, conn);
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?username",MySqlDbType.VarChar,30);
    adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("?password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
    adapter.Update(dt);
    ...
    ...
 }
```

I tried that but the values in MySQL server did not change accordingly.

Note: I want to update values located in DataTable dt (dt.Rows[0]["username"],dt.Rows[0]["password"]) , I dont want to specify values manually.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AddWithValue

```
adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",dt.Rows[0]["username"].ToString());
```

Won't this work?

Comment: I want to update values located in DataTable dt (dt.Rows[0]["username"],dt.Rows[0]["password"])

Comment: Then just add in the datatable value like i show in my answer.

Comment: I have to to it manually? there is no other solution which check the data in the DataTable.Rows[0] and then assign it as a parameter? If not why I need to give 'adapter.Update' DataTable as parameter?

Comment: It's good practice to pass parameters because you protect yourself from SQL injection.  http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few things wrong in your code. First of all, you need to use `@` sign to specify your parameters.

From [`5.1.4 Working with Parameters`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html)

> Note that the parameter is preceded by an '@' symbol to indicate it is
>   to be treated as a parameter.

And you didn't specify values to your parameters. You just declared their parameters but you didn't add any values to them. Assing your `.Value` property their values. Or you can use `AddWithValue` method as an alternative. With `AddWithValue` method, you don't need to specify their types. I don't see any MySqlConnection in your code also. You defined `conn` in `MySqlCommand` but you didn't use it and open it anywhere. And you need to use [`.Fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method before you use [`.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

For example;

```
 public static int update(DataTable dt, string id, string table)
 {
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
       MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
       adapter.UpdateCommand = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE " + table + " SET username=@username,password=@password WHERE id=" + id, conn);
       adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@username",MySqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value = usernameValue;
       adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = passwordValue;
       conn.Open(); 
       adapter.Fill(dt);
       adapter.Update(dt);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I want to update values located in DataTable dt (dt.Rows[0]["username"],dt.Rows[0]["password"]) , I dont want to specify values manually.